# I want my while loop to stop when the user types "done"

Tags: java, loops

It's a Text speak converter and it works until I want it to end when the user says "done". What command would I use for that?

```
package textspeak;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class TextSpeak {
    byte textspeak;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            String brb = new String("brb");
            String omw = new String("omw");
            String btw = new String("btw");
            String lol = new String("lol");
            String omg = new String("omg");
            String rofl = new String("rofl");
            String fyi = new String("fyi");
            String ftw = new String("ftw");
            String idk = new String("idk");
            String jk = new String("jk");
            String ikr = new String("ikr");
            String smh = new String("smh");
            String ttyl = new String("ttyl");
            String rn = new String("rn");
            String nvm = new String("nvm");
            String ily = new String("ily");
            String done = new String("done");

            System.out.println("Hello! I convert 'text speak' into real english. Type in a commonly used shortcut for a word or phrase and I'll try to convert it. Type 'done' when you're done.");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String user_input = scan.nextLine();
            while (!user_input.isEmpty()){  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<What command do I need to put here?
            user_input = scan.nextLine();
                if (user_input.equals(brb)){
                System.out.println("Be Right Back");}
                if (user_input.equals(omw)){
                    System.out.println("On My way");}
                if (user_input.equals(btw)){
                    System.out.println("By The Way");}
                if (user_input.equals(lol)){
                    System.out.println("Laughing Out Loud");}
                if (user_input.equals(omg)){
                    System.out.println("Oh My Gosh");}
                if (user_input.equals(rofl)){
                    System.out.println("Rolling On the Floor Laughing");}
                if (user_input.equals(fyi)){
                    System.out.println("For Your Information");}
                if (user_input.equals(ftw)){
                    System.out.println("For The Win");}
                if (user_input.equals(idk)){
                    System.out.println("I Don't Know");}
                if (user_input.equals(jk)){
                    System.out.println("Just Kidding");}
                if (user_input.equals(ikr)){
                    System.out.println("I Know, Right?");}
                if (user_input.equals(smh)){
                    System.out.println("Shaking My Head");}
                if (user_input.equals(ttyl)){
                    System.out.println("Talk To You Later");}
                if (user_input.equals(rn)){
                    System.out.println("Right Now");}
                if (user_input.equals(nvm)){
                    System.out.println("Nevermind");}
                if (user_input.equals(ily)){
                    System.out.println("I Love You");} 
                                    }
            }//end of while loop
        }
```

Comment: The question amounts to "How can I end a loop in Java?" Read the trail on [Flow-control Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html), and consider investing in a book.

Answer (score 6):

Try doing:

```
while (!user_input.equals("done"))
```

Or as [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2400454/jay) said you can `break` inside the loop:

```
if (user_input.equals("done")) {
    break;
}
```

That takes you outside of the loop. For example:

```
while (true) {
    break;
    System.out.println("Inside");
}
System.out.println("Outside");
```

Would print just:

> Outside

Answer (score 2):

Although [Anubian Noobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2197700/anubian-noob) makes sense you can also do it this way inside the while:

```
if (user_input.equals("Done")) break;
```

Comment: I find it bad practice to break from a loop if you dont need to, you adding more exit paths to the loop, more 'logic' and more room for error.

Comment: Its a matter of preference. Its the same Idea as checking corner cases. Or input cases. When you don't want to change a lot of code for a small requirement. Time vs readability plays a factor

Comment: It's not a bad thing to know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you use a [`Map<String, String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to store your acronyms. That way, you can simplify your code into something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> acronyms = new HashMap<>();
    acronyms.put("brb", "Be Right Back");
    acronyms.put("omw", "On My way");
    acronyms.put("btw", "By The Way");
    acronyms.put("lol", "Laughing Out Loud");
    acronyms.put("omg", "Oh My Gosh");
    acronyms.put("rofl", "Rolling On the Floor Laughing");
    acronyms.put("fyi", "For Your Information");
    acronyms.put("ftw", "For The Win");
    acronyms.put("idk", "I Don't Know");
    acronyms.put("jk", "Just Kidding");
    acronyms.put("ikr", "I Know, Right?");
    acronyms.put("smh", "Shaking My Head");
    acronyms.put("ttyl", "Talk To You Later");
    acronyms.put("rn", "Right Now");
    acronyms.put("nvm", "Nevermind");
    acronyms.put("ily", "I Love You");
    acronyms.put("done", "Goodbye");
    System.out.println("Hello! I convert 'text speak' into real english. Type "
                + "in a commonly used shortcut for a word or phrase "
                + "and I'll try to convert it. Type 'done' when you're done.");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = null;
        do {
            line = scan.nextLine().trim();
            String str = acronyms.get(line);
            System.out.println((str != null) ? str : "Unknown: " + line);
        } while (!line.equalsIgnoreCase("done") && scan.hasNextLine());
    }
}
```